# Downloading ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation

Whenever I go to the Esri website to download ArcGIS Desktop, it always directs me to download ArcGIS Pro.

Can someone provide me with the Esri link to the ArcGIS Desktop download?

Comment: What "Esri website" link are you going to when you do not find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArcGIS **Desktop** is comprised of multiple components (ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro being two of the major ones). For ArcMap, check out [this link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/).

I would recommend chatting with a representative to ensure that you aren't over-purchasing what license level you need. Many users only need the [personal use](https://store.esri.com/content/esri/en-us/arcgis_for_personal_use.html) package, for non-commercial applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you never tested the ArcGIS you can download the trial version (21-days) in this link:

http://www.esri.com/arcgis/trial

Other good choice is the student version ($100/year)

http://www.esri.com/landing-pages/education-promo

If you are not a student, go to this link:

http://www.esri.com/locations